# extend the markdown jupyter nbconvert template to remove codeblocks but keep markdown output from codeblocks

Tags: python, jupyter-notebook, markdown, nbconvert

I need to extend the nbconvert markdown template to remove code blocks but preserve the output of codeblocks. I'm struggling to find the appropriate documentation for nbconvert. The [official documentation](https://nbconvert.readthedocs.io/en/latest/customizing.html) is very vague and assumes intimate familiarity with jinja templates.

For example, I have a code block that contains:

```
from IPython.display import display, Markdown

display(Markdown('# Title\n\n This is text\n\n `this is code`'))
```

The built-in markdown template produces the following output when run with `!jupyter nbconvert --to markdown --template my_template my_notebook.ipynb`

````
\```python
from IPython.display import display, Markdown

display(Markdown('# Title\n\n This is text\n\n `this is code`'))
\```


# Title

 This is text

 `this is code`
````

I would like the template to ignore the source and only provide the output:

```
# Title

 This is text

 `this is code`
```

I've tried adding meta-data to the cell and removing it with this:

**metadata**

```
{
 "hide_input": true
}
```

**template directive**

```
{% block data_codecell scoped %}
  {% if cell.metadata.get('hide_input', True) %}
{{ output.data['text/markdown'] }}
  {% endif %}

{% endblock data_codecell %}
```

That does not appear to work and yields the same results.

I can remove the codeblock and the output entirely by using, but that does not solve the larger problem of preserving the output.

```
{% block codecell %}
{% endblock codecell %}
```

Any help or a pointer to example templates or documentation is greatly appreciated. The example [templates provided by ipython/jupyter](https://github.com/ipython/ipython/wiki/Cookbook:%20nbconvert%20templates) are a bit thin in documentation and there are relatively few examples.

Comment: This is an idea for a workaround. You could read in the `.py` file afterwards line by line and delete all lines which start with `import` or `from`. But I see this is not the most elegant way to do it.

Comment: @mosc I'm not quite sure what you mean -- the resulting output is a `.md` file and contains pretty much flat text.

Comment: I see. I thought the output is a python file. My fault. I am sorry. But it is possible to manipulate the file afterwards. Maybe using regular expressions to remove the lines you do not want.